# Unify the implementations of a generic interface

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, types, interface

I am trying to find a way to **group collection of types** that implement a **generic** interface.

Here is what i have as a test setup

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace Example
{
    public interface ITypeA { }
    public interface ITypeB { }

    public class DescendantA1 : ITypeA { }
    public class DescendantA2 : ITypeA { }

    public class DescendantB1 : ITypeB { }
    public class DescendantB2 : ITypeB { }

    public interface ITypesMapper<in TTypeA, out TTypeB>
        where TTypeA : ITypeA
        where TTypeB : ITypeB
    {
        TTypeB Map(TTypeA typeA);
    }

    public class FirstMapper : ITypesMapper<DescendantA1, DescendantB1>
    {
        public DescendantB1 Map(DescendantA1 typeA) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public class SecondMapper : ITypesMapper<DescendantA2, DescendantB2>
    {
        public DescendantB2 Map(DescendantA2 typeA) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<ITypesMapper<ITypeA, ITypeB>> types = new List<ITypesMapper<ITypeA, ITypeB>>();
            types.Add(new FirstMapper());
            types.Add(new SecondMapper());
        }
    }
}
```

The issue with the above example is that I cannot add `FirstMapper` and `SecondMapper` to a collection, since I do not have an interface that captures both of them. (The C# compiler says it cannot convert `FirstMapper and SecondMapper` to `ITypesMapper<TTypeA, TTypeB>`

I thought that by having my interface's generic paramters restricted to types that inherit the `ITypeA` and `ITypeB` interfaces, and making them co/contravariant I would achieve this.

---

One way I could fix this is by changing my `Mapper` classes to inherit `ITypesMapper<ITypeA, ITypeB>`, but then I would loose the strongly typed objects in their **Map()** method and I would have to cast. I do not want this.

Another way would be to define an `IMapper` interface, that will be inherited by `ITypesMapper<,,>`, but then I cannot define the `Map()` method to work with generic arguments.

---

I am wondering if there is a way to create a set of Mapper classes (as `FirstMapper` and `SecondMapper`), each of which must have a **Map** method that can work with generic parameters **and** have a way to unify all of them under the same interface, that I can then call.

**I am ok with changing everything in my design**, I just need to have:

- An interface that I can put them all behind (so that they can be in a collection).
- The interface should expose the **ITypeB Map(ITypeA input)** method
- The concrete mapper implementations should work with concrete types (so a mapper should have a `DescendantB1 Map(DescendantA1 typeA)` and not `ITypeB Map(ITypeA input)`

Comment: `IEnumerable<String>` can be cast to `IEnumerable<Object>` because any string that comes out of it is an object. `IList<String>` cannot be cast to `IList<Object>` because any object *added* to it may not be a string. The type parameter to `IEnumerable<T>` is an `out` parameter. Your `TTypeA` parameter is `in`, which gets you in trouble. If you could change that to `out`, you're good. But you can't. That leaves you with Plan B: A non-generic "base" interface `ITypesMapper`, analogous to `System.Collections.IList`.

Comment: Yes, but by having a "base" interface I loose the ability to provide a "Map" method, that can be called on all mappers. :(

Comment: Why would you lose that?

Comment: Because if I do leave something like `ITypeB Map(ITypeA input)`, then I lock my dervied mapper classes to have the same interface, and I want to have the concrete types in each of my mappers - DerviedTypeB Map(DervivedTypeA input)

Comment: I see an inconsistency between requirements 2 and 3. Point 2 defines the interface, but the third point says that the signature on the implementations must work with concrete types. Perhaps the second point is intended to read, "...should expose the TTypeB Map(TTypeA input) method"? If that is the case, then it becomes clear why Ed's solution doesn't work here. If you move that function definition up a level to an interface without generics, you of course can't use TTypeA and TTypeB. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Kobek The base interface can be empty, or the child interfaces can implement it explicitly. Certainly, your generic Map() prototype is the whole point of the exercise, and it would hardly make sense to give that up. But `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` [implements `System.Collections.IList` explicitly](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs).

Comment: @chill94, yes. I guess the correct definition is that the interface should expose the `TTypeB Map(TTypeA input)`. The whole point of this is that I can have a collection that consists of multiple mappers, and I can call the Map method on any one of them, and that can return to me an object that is of `ITypeB` type.

Comment: @EdPlunkett yes, indeed i should not give my map() method up.
But if I do declare it in the base interface, I need to have my dervied classes use it as is - they cannot have the concrete types. I am not sure how implementing it explicitly can help me in any way.

The more and more we discuss this, the more and more I seem to think, that what I want to achieve is not really possible :(

Comment: @Kobek Implementing it explicitly lets you have an *explicit* non-generic `ITypeB ITypesMapper.Map(ITypeA typeA);` method which satisfies the explicitly implemented non-generic interface **but which does not conflict with** generic `public TTypeB Map(ITypeA TypeA);`. Just like `List<T>` does it in the linked reference source: `int System.Collections.IList.Add(Object item)` and `public int Add(T item)`. But we do still have a question of how you're going to use these things when you retrieve them from the collection.

Comment: @EdPlunkett exactly. If I implement it explicitly I need to implement it like
`ITypeB IMapper.Map(ITypeA input) => this.Map((DescendantA1)input);` - so basically making the explicit implementation call the concrete one. But with that approach I will need to cast the input to the concrete type first. And if im going to cast, I might as well just have the base interface with the `ITypeB Map(ITypeA input)`, and then all concrete implementations will cast to whatever they need inside their Map implementation.

Comment: @Kobek Storing then is trivial, as shown. Let’s talk about use. Please provide more detail about how you plan to use them. It seems to me that at the point of use, all concrete types must be known at compile time. Is that correct?

Comment: They (the concrete types) are known, but which one is used depends on a *runtime parameter*. Part of the interface is an `Id` field, which is an `int`. At runtime, I get this `Id` and find which mapper in the collection has it, then I involve its `Map` method and return the result of that `Map` method to the rest of the system.

Comment: So your mapper takes an `ITypeA` of concrete type unknown at compile time, and gives you an `ITypeB` of concrete type unknown at compile time? Generics can be part of the answer, but at that point, either you've got to be able to cast that `ITypeB` to some concrete type known at compile time, or you've got to be able to do everything you need to do with it via non-generic OOP: virtuals, interfaces, etc. Generics are a very poor fit for dynamic stuff like this. Use 'em all you like inside the concrete implementations of the classes, of course.

Comment: The Lord invented generics to let us have a typesafe list of integers or a typesafe list of strings, without having to write two list classes. The intent was never to let you use the same reference for both of those lists. That's a different problem and you need to solve it with different tools.

Comment: why not using Automapper Nuget package to address your mapping problem?

Comment: @Zinov - because my mapping logic will be quite complex, and I prefer to have a standalone unit that I can easily test. Automapper just gets in the way.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I agree with you. I wanted to see if I can solve my problem by taking advantage of generics - but they dont seem to be quite the right fit for this problem. Thanks for helping. :)

Comment: @Kobek you can do complex logic as well with automapper, you can pass parameters for the mappings, you can work with the conventions and in top of that it is very useful with your generic approach as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the closest I think you can get (this solution also demonstrates the issues with what you're trying to do) -

```
public interface ITypeA { }
public interface ITypeB { }

public class DescendantA1 : ITypeA { }
public class DescendantA2 : ITypeA { }

public class DescendantB1 : ITypeB { }
public class DescendantB2 : ITypeB { }

public interface ITypeMapper<in TTypeA, out TTypeB>
{
    TTypeB Map(TTypeA typeA);
}

public abstract class TypesMapper<TTypeA, TTypeB>: ITypeMapper<ITypeA, ITypeB>
    where TTypeA : ITypeA
    where TTypeB : ITypeB 
{
    public ITypeB Map(ITypeA typeA) => internalMap(typeA);

    protected abstract TTypeB internalMap(TTypeA a);
}

public class FirstMapper : TypesMapper<DescendantA1, DescendantB1>
{
    protected override DescendantB1 internalMap(DescendantA1 typeA) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public class SecondMapper : TypesMapper<DescendantA2, DescendantB2>
{
    protected override DescendantB2 internalMap(DescendantA2 typeA) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public static class ProgramTest
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ITypeMapper<ITypeA, ITypeB>> types = new List<ITypeMapper<ITypeA, ITypeB>>();
        types.Add(new FirstMapper());
        types.Add(new SecondMapper());
    }
}
```

The error you get here is in the following line:

```
public ITypeB Map(ITypeA typeA) => internalMap(typeA);
```

Telling us that we can't convert ITypeA (base) to TTypeA (concrete).

Now, we can add a class constraint to the generic abstract class definition, ie.

```
where TTypeA : class, ITypeA
```

And cast the line that's giving the error:

```
public ITypeB Map(ITypeA typeA) => internalMap(typeA as TTypeA);
```

But there's nothing preventing the consumer of this list from calling Map(...) with an argument that is not TTypeA, which is why this whole scheme isn't type safe to begin with. Nonetheless, if you're using some sort of inspection and you really are only going to call the Map function with the correct concrete type, I think this would get you where you want to go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I went ahead and did a similliar thing - by using what @EdPlunkett suggested, and Implemented the base mapper explicitly, and then made that call my generic type. So almost the same as what you provided as an answer. 

As for it being unsafe - yes I am aware of that. I do have a mechanism that will guarantee  I am calling it with the correct type. The only issue that might occur is in the future - someone else can misuse the code quite easily.